# CNN for classification of numerical dataset in CSV file

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to apply a CNN on my numerical dataset from a CSV file, but I have problems with the dimensions. My Dataset consists of 26 Features/Columns and 1200 rows/samples. The dataset has 3 labels.

```
Dataset = pd.read_csv("...", header=0)
features = ['...']
x = Dataset [features]
y = Dataset .Classifier
sc = PowerTransformer()
x = sc.fit_transform(x)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=0.75)

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=8, verbose=1)

accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(accuracy)
```

I get the following error:
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (900, 26)

I am not sure how to reshape the data. As far as I know I only need a vector.

Answer (score 0):

You are partly correct. You do need a vector, but it has to be of different dimensions. 
Conv1D layer takes as input: 
Input shape:
3+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)

In the model.fit function you set your batch size to 8. This means that you have to give sets of 8 samples per step (step = iteration before the network weights are updated).
What you have to do is generate sets (or batches) of 8 samples and then feed them to your network.

Comment: Oh, okay. I see. It works now, thank you very much. The accuracy is pretty bad so far and I suppose a MLP is better anyway, but i want to try CNN too.

I don't have any experience with anything else than MLP. I got this architecture from some random example i found online. 
Do you maybe have a recommendation about a architecture for a NN with convolution layers, LSTM and even a few others if it makes sense? 
I would like to experiment a bit to improve the accuracy, but don't realy know where to start and it's pretty hard to find an example with a numerical dataset online.

Comment: You should check the MNIST dataset, it's an introductory dataset exactly right for people new to convolutional neural networks and machine learning vision. You could try a ResNet or DenseNet or any other architecture provided by keras. It's rather easy to get going and then experiment with your own ideas from there.
https://keras.io/api/applications/